# Redux state doesn't update with action dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I've gone through every piece of documentation and example project I can find for building a react app with redux and react-router, but I just can't seem to figure out how to get my redux state to update when I dispatch actions. As you can see in this screenshot, actions are dispatching properly, but my store/nextState isn't updating.

[image]

**ACTION:**

```
export function updateUsername(username) {
  return { type: types.UPDATE_USERNAME, username };
}
```

**REDUCER (EDIT: I've tried both of these variations):**

```
   /* first variation */
   const username = (
      state = '',
      action,
    ) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case types.UPDATE_USERNAME:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
            username: action.username,
          });
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };

  /* second variation */
  const username = (
    state = '',
    action,
  ) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case types.UPDATE_USERNAME:
        return action.username;
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
```

**REDUCER COMBINATION:**

```
const user = combineReducers({
  isAuthenticated,
  token,
  password,
  username,
});

export default user;
```

**REDUCERS/INDEX.JS:**

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  isFetching,
  open,
  search,
  user,
  routing: routerReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**STORE CONFIGURATION:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import * as actions from '../actions';

function configureStore(history, initialState) {
  const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

  const enhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__();

  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware,
        loggerMiddleware,
        routerMiddleware(history),
      ),
      enhancer,
    ),
  );

  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
      const nextReducer = rootReducer;
      store.replaceReducer(nextReducer);
    });
  }

  return store;
}

export default configureStore;
```

**STORE CREATION:**

```
const initialState = {};

const store = configureStore(browserHistory, initialState);
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);
const routes = createRoutes(store);


render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

**AND FINALLY, THE COMPONENT:**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import validator from 'validator';
import className from 'classnames';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import * as AuthActions from '../../actions/AuthActions';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleUsernameChange = this.handleUsernameChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleUsernameChange(e) {
    this.props.actions.updateUsername(validator.escape(e.target.value.trim()));
  }

  handlePasswordChange(e) {
    this.props.actions.updatePassword(validator.escape(e.target.value.trim()));
  }

  handleSubmit(e, getState) {
    e.prevent.default();
    const user = { username: this.props.user.username, password: this.props.user.password };
    console.log(user);
    this.props.actions.loginUser(user);
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className='login-form'>
            <TextField
              type="username"
              autoFocus="true"
              floatingLabelText="Username"
              floatingLabelFixed={true}
              autoComplete="off"
              onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}
              />
            <br/>
            <TextField
              type="password"
              autoFocus="true"
              floatingLabelText="Password"
              floatingLabelFixed={true}
              autoComplete="off"
              onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}
              />
          </form>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: state.user,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(AuthActions, dispatch),
  };
}


export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(LoginForm);
```

I've been stuck on this for a week now, so any help you can offer would be GREATLY appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are those codes correct? You show a UPDATE_USERNAME in the log... but the action code provide is UPDATE_PASSWORD

Comment: Good catch. Just copy/pasted the wrong action. Edited!

Comment: Can you provide a repo so I can clone and run?

Comment: @LucasKatayama I'll put together a repo that you can clone in the morning. Until then I've  found a workaround by declaring "return state = action.username" for each of my reducers. Not ideal, but it's working.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't run your code, so I can't say offhand if just this will fix it, but your username reducer is returning an object with a `username` property, when it should be returning the `action.username` string.

```
const username = (state = '', action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.UPDATE_USERNAME:
      return action.username
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Also, have you verified that you don't have a typo in your `types` declaration? I see that in your reducer you reference `types.UPDATE_USERNAME`, but in your action creator you set the type using the string `UPDATE_USERNAME`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried that format for the reducer, along with a number of other variations as well.   None seem to be working. As far as the types declaration, I imported '* as types' in my reducer file. I'll try switching that up now.

Comment: Have you thrown a `console.log` into your `username` reducer to ensure that it is being called? (or just added a breakpoint in the devtools)

Comment: Yup, it's firing. I'm getting a 200 from my backend authorization service when I dispatch my login action, too, but the same issue with nextState not updating.

Comment: Well, I'm still not seeing anything. Have you tried stepping through the reducer returned by `combineReducers` with a debugger? https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/v3.6.0/src/combineReducers.js#L141-L156 That should verify the return values of all of your reducer functions.

Comment: So I found a bit of a work around, but it's throwing all sorts of eslint errors: By changing the "return action.username" to "return state = action.username", my state up updating with all dispatches. The error eslint is throwing though is "Return statement should not contain assignment". But hey, if it works it works...

Comment: You should keep state mutable. Setting as "state=something" can change whole state of application. Instead, it is expected to return state from a reducer as "return Object.assign({}, state, action);"

Answer (score 0):

In my case: I had a `user` object which I get from `useSelector` states, then I updated the user's role and it wouldn't recognize that it is a new object, so I copied the object with `Object.assign({}, user)` then triggered `dispatch`

```
const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
user.role = Roles.admin;
dispatch(setUser(Object.assign({}, user)));
```